# React Query Developer Tools

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have this error

No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one

even though I already wrapped my components in QueryClientProvider

This is my current Main.jsx code

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
        <ReactQueryDevtools />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I also have this routes setup in my Main.jsx

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<MainPage />}>
      {/* Public Routes */}
      <Route index={true} element={<AuthPage />} />

      {/* Faculty Routes */}

      {/* Admin Routes */}

      {/* Superadmin Routes */}
      <Route element={<Authorization allowedRole="superadmin" />}>
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<h1>Room Page</h1>} />
        <Route path="/rooms">
          <Route index={true} element={<RoomPage />} />
          <Route path="add" element={<RoomFormPage />} />
          <Route
            path=":roomId/edit"
            element={<RoomFormPage />}
            loader={editRoomLoader}
          />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/faculty" element={<h1>Room Page</h1>} />
        <Route path="/faculty-types" element={<h1>Room Page</h1>} />
        <Route path="/courses" element={<h1>Room Page</h1>} />
        <Route path="/users" element={<h1>Users Page</h1>} />
        <Route path="/programs" element={<h1>Programs Page</h1>} />
        <Route
          path="/academic-qualifications"
          element={<h1>Academic Qualification Page</h1>}
        />
        <Route path="/year-levels" element={<h1>Curriculum Page</h1>} />
        <Route path="/school-years" element={<h1>Curriculum Page</h1>} />
      </Route>

      {/* Error Routes */}
      <Route path="/unauthorized" element={<h1>Error 403, Unauthorized</h1>} />
      <Route path="*" element={<h1>Error 404, Page Not Found</h1>} />
    </Route>
  )
);
```

I used React Query in one of the element in Route and it works fine but when I start to add the ReactQueryDevtools it starts to show the error.

I have this code in my rooms routes and it works fine.

```
  const { isLoading, refetch, status } = useQuery(
    ["rooms", perPage, page],
    getRooms,
    {
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        setRooms(
          data.rooms.map((e) => {
            return {
              ...e,
              action: (
                <CommonAction
                  id={e._id}
                  onDelete={deleteHandler}
                  deleteQuery={deleteRoom}
                />
              ),
            };
          })
        );
        setTotalRows(data.count);
      },
    }
  );
```

Comment: What does `console.log(queryClient)` prints?

Comment: QueryClient2
defaultOptions: {}
mutationCache: MutationCache2 {listeners: Array(0), config: {…}, mutations: Array(0), mutationId: 0}
mutationDefaults: []
queryCache: QueryCache2 {listeners: Array(0), config: {…}, queries: Array(0), queriesMap: {…}}
queryDefaults: []
unsubscribeFocus: ƒ ()
unsubscribeOnline: ƒ ()



this is my import in QueryClient
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";

Comment: Can you include `package.json` in your question?